# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC controller not receiving data from AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm getting a 500 error, whenever I try to grab data from my controller using ajax. It seems that the controller is not reading the Guid at all, even though the id has been passed correctly to the ajax function

Here is my function call in Ajax:

```js
const handleDetails = (id) => {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Monsters/Details',
    data: id,
    success: function (result) {
      alert('Successfully received Data ');
      console.log(result);
    },
    error: function () {
      alert('Failed to receive the Data');
      console.log('Failed ');
    }
  })
}
```

Here is my controller:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(Guid id)
{
    return View(await _monstersData.GetMonsters(id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, in the ajax call I cannot pass the id directly. I need to pass it as an object

```js
const handleDetails = (id) => {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Monsters/Details',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: {id: id},
    success: function (result) {
      alert('Successfully received Data ');
      console.log(result);
    },
    error: function () {
      alert('Failed to receive the Data');
      console.log('Failed ');
    }
  })
}
```